# Algorithm to return the smallest integer in the whole set

Tags: c++

I can't seem to get my head around the off-line minimum algo. Can someone explain it to me more?
Possibly with pseudo-code in a "near-code" fashion.
Say, for example, that I have the following sequence:

```
"5","4","6","E","1","7","E","E","3","2"
```

**What are the steps to return the smallest integer in the whole set.** I understand the problem but I don't seem to find a way to code it.

Regards

Comment: I must be missing something but this is trivial with `std::set`.

Comment: @rubenvb No need to keep every integer in memory just to find the smallest.

Comment: How come the two "E":s make the "3" and the "2" skipped? Because there's no "ending" "E" or?

Comment: Is `E` a number? Should it be ignored? Are you parsing this as user input?

Comment: @NeilKirk sure you do, you don't know how many of them you'll need to extract before you "read" all of them leading up to the current element of the input. But then again there may be duplicates, so `std::multiset` would be useful.

Comment: If I understand it correctly (please correct me if I'm wrong) The "E":s are endings of a subset. So in my example, if I "step" to the first "E" it's in position 3 (counting from 0). Then I have a subset of 3 integers (5, 4 and 6). The smallest of these is 4. So that's the first one to choose. Is that correct?

Comment: @guitarm63 I think you need to elaborate on what the "it" is in "if I Understand it correctly".

Comment: "it" = finding the smallest value in a subset of integers up to an "E". But I realize I don't get the whole picture...

Comment: @guitarm63 [this link](http://llhuii.is-programmer.com/posts/31126.html) might help. You need to consider all integers encountered up to an 'E'.

Comment: @rubenvb What are you talking about? Why do you even care about duplicates? You only want the smallest.

Comment: The answer should supposedly be that three integers are returned: 4, 1 and 5. I don't understand how the five (5) gets returned. The one (1) must come from beeing the smallest from one (1) and seven (7) in the second subset.

Comment: @Neil imagine the input `1,4,4,5,E,6,E,E`. That should return `1,4,4`. You need to store all previously encountered numbers until you hit an E. Then you can move one to the result set, but you can't discard them any sooner.

Comment: @rubenvb That's exactly what I'm talking about!

Comment: @rubenvb Ok I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had nothing better to do, an example implementation leveraging the power of the Standard Library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> offline_minima(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
  std::vector<int> result;
  std::multiset<int> numbers; // handles duplicate input like in 4,4,5,E,4,6,E,E
  for(int i : input)
  {
    if(i == 'E') // We need to extract the minimum
    {
      if(numbers.empty())
        throw -42; // shouldn't happen with valid input
      result.push_back(*(std::begin(numbers))); // store the minimum number
      numbers.erase(std::begin(numbers)); // remove the minimum number from our sorted numbers
    }
    else
      numbers.insert(i); // store the new number in the sorted set numbers
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  const std::vector<int> input{ 5, 4, 6, 'E', 1, 7, 'E', 'E', 3, 2 };
  const auto result = offline_minima(input);

  for(int i : result)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633662dcba4d7618).
Note I misuse the fact that characters like `'E'` can be converted to an `int` and thus if the array contains the value `69` this will be misinterpreted as an `E`. But the question isn't about input validation/processing so I left that as a featbugre.

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to give you the code they wont.
In terms of this particular problem with the list you have given you can either
1) sort it then start from the begining to find the smallest integer
2) just run through every number

You can keep a temporary variable to keep the current lowest. Then step through and compare it to this variable. If it is lower then set that value to the lowest value.

Once you have finished stepping through them all you just return the value of that temporary variable.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work when there are two extract operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:-

1) Set min variable to INT_MAX.

2) Start extracting strings one by one. If they represent integers then compare that with the min value you stored. If it's smaller than change min to that value. If it's greater than move to next element.

3) At the end you would have min element with you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some calls from the standard library which do what you asked for. They are probably not the most efficient ones.

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"5","4","6","E","1","7","E","E","3","2"};
std::vector<std::string> r{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

//remove all elements which are not numbers
std::vector<std::string> v_numbers;
std::set_intersection(v.begin(), v.end(), r.begin(), r.end()
                    , std::back_inserter(v_numbers));

//find minimum element
std::string result = *std::min_element(v_numbers.begin(), v_numbers.end());
std::cout<<result<<std::endl;
```

This prints `1`.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/e.js/sfZ8h4)

---

**EDIT:** Note that in the current form, it will work only for single-digit numbers. If that isn't sufficient, either remove all `"E"` in front of the `set_intersection` -- if `"E"` is your only letter. Or generate a string-vector `r` which ends with a larger number than `"9"`. Or do something completely different.